# Is React 16's Portal API meant to replace the Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, portal, react-fiber

I noticed new feature `portals` do the same thing but better? I dont know much about portals but it seems to be the new way to manage nested component updates? 
I knew Reacts [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) was experimental, and noticed `componentDidUpdate` no longer receives `prevContext` and they dropped `contextTypes`.

I also noticed they are introducing [React 16's Portal API](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) and not sure if this is intended to replace the Context API.

So again, as mentioned above, is React 16's Portal API meant to replace the Context API?

EDIT: To piggyback on this topic, is conext the best way to manage i18n localization in react?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** => `Portals` and `Context` solve different purposes, one is to inject DOM at any level and other is to inject props at any level. `Context` can mimic `Portals` but `Portals` AS OF NOW cannot mimic `Context` not at least without introducing code smell.

**NOTE:** Below is based on my understanding of the two concepts, if anyone has further thoughts or corrections on this please feel free to edit the answer.

From what I was able to understand `Portals` are, as the name suggests, a door way for you to render components that need not be in the component tree hierarchy. This works like perfectly for `Modals`, `Popovers` or any component which needs to be stitched at a particular location in the tree.

`Context` is to communicate with various sibling and child components without having to pass props all the way down from parent to the intended component. Of course, this is an important feature to have but it remained in the experimental phase probably due to the fact that this can be achieved by `event-emitters` and `Redux`, `MobX` for a centralized state management.

I am assuming that your use case for `i18n` would require a lot of communication across components for which you might want to look at this great article

[**COMPONENT COMMUNICATION**](https://www.andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/)

[image]

Portals and Context help achieving this kind of communication but there is a difference. Portals can render or inject DOM at any level and Context can inject props at any level in the subcomponent tree.

You can always achieve what `Portals` are able to do using `Context` but I don't think `Portals` can mimic `Context` functionality.

**EG:** Something like this can be done to mimic what `Portals` do using `Context`. Where as in `Portals` AFAIK you can only send DOM Nodes `ReactDOM.createPortal(child, container)`. May be there is a way to achieve the functionality but that would surely lead to code smell.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            renderModal: this.renderModal
        }
    }

    renderModal = (children) => {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.state.open,
            injectableChildren: children
        })
    }

    render() {
        this.state.open
            ?
            <div>
                {this.state.injectableChildren}
            </div>
            : 
            null
        // JSX
    }
}


class SomeSibling extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
       renderModal: React.PropTypes.func
    }

    handleOnClick = (event) => {
        this.context.renderModal(renderableChildJSX);
    }

    renderableChildJSX = () => (
        <div>
            YAY I AM GETTING RENDERED AT THE ROOT
        </div>
    )

    render() {
        return(
            <div onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my case, I feared from using `Context` despite it's flexibility due to the fact that `React` docs always mentioned that it's an experimental feature and warned repeatedly from using this feature full-blown. My guess is that React is looking at stabilising this feature or completely scrape it off the React codebase which is a risk that could go both ways.

**CONCLUSION:** IMO, `Portals` in it's current state and the problem it is trying to resolve is entirely different from what `Context` is built for and it is better to use `event-emitters` with the only reason that `Context` might possibly be deprecated.

Comment: Hey but as it is mentioned for portals in react documentation, that props will be available to portal as if its a regular children of the component. In this way props can be sent to any location in react hierarchy . Dont you think it is some what like context??

Comment: But how can you send props from Parent to 4th grand child? Unless you mention the 4th child `<Child4 parentProps={...} />` in your Parent's render method, while 3rd child also renders `<Child4 props={...} />`. I wasn't able to come up with a proper example to demonstrate why it's not a good idea to use Portals to communicate props but if you encountered any use case please feel free to add it to the answer.

Comment: usign 'this.context.' are you using the new or old portal?

Answer (score 1):

A Portal API is different from a Context API,

> `Portals` provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
>   that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

A portal is useful when you might want to render Modals or Popovers, that need to be outside of the current DOM hierarchy in order for it to have proper z-indexes. Most often you would render these in the top level directly. However with Portal you can render DOM element at any level of hierarchy.

In `React 16`, portals can be created like

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(child, container)
```

`Context` on the other hand is used to pass the data onto different component without the need to pass if down at each level. You may have components at different level, some of which may be extremely nested and passing the props down all the way at each level might not be a great solution and it comes with significant performance hindrance, since a lot the higher levels may not actually be using these props but will still re-render on such prop changes.

From v16.3.0 React has introduced a new [`context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) and context is no longer experimental.

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for
>   a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user,
>   theme, or preferred language. Using context, we can avoid passing
>   props through intermediate elements. but it shouldn't be used to just
>   pass props a few levels down

In general you would use context like

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

class Provider extends React.Component {
   state = {
       theme: 'dark'
   }
   handleChange=() => {}

   render() {
        return <MyContext.Provider 
           value={{state: this.state, handleChange: this.handleChange}}
           >
               {this.props.children}
           </MyContext.Provider?>
   }
}
```

and for the Component you want to use context value, you would write

```
import {MyContext} from 'path/to/context'
...
render() {
    return <MyContext.Consumer>
         {(theme) => <div>{theme}</div>}
     </MyContext.Consumer>
}
```

> To piggyback on this topic, is context the best way to manage i18n
>   localisation in react?

Yes i18n localisation is a good usecase for using context since you would need to pass on language/paramerisation selection throughout your app. In cases where you need much more integration with APIs to do localisation, you can think about using Redux.

For more details check this answer on [`whether to use Context or Redux`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073/react-context-vs-react-redux-when-should-i-use-each-one/49569183#49569183)