# React Context vs React Redux, when should I use each one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

[React 16.3.0 was released](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html) and the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API is not an experimental feature anymore. Dan Abramov (the creator of Redux) wrote a good comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428355/react-with-redux-what-about-the-context-issue) about this, but it was 2 years when Context was still an Experimental feature.

My question is, in your opinion/experience when should I use **React Context** over **React Redux** and vice versa?

Comment: If you are comparing Redux and React Context API, it's because you only want to keep vars on sync between components. Check the `duix` npm package. It's only a simple state manager with callbacks, really easy to implement.
Just to be clear: I'm the creator.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

As **Context** is no longer an experimental feature and you can use Context in your application directly and it is going to be great for passing down data to deeply nested components which what it was designed for.

As Mark Erikson has written in his [blog](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/):

> If you're only using Redux to avoid passing down props, context could
> replace Redux - but then you probably didn't need Redux in the first
> place.
>
> Context also doesn't give you anything like the `Redux DevTools`, the
> ability to trace your state updates, `middleware` to add centralized
> application logic, and other powerful capabilities that `Redux`
> enables.

`Redux` is much more powerful and provides a large number of features that the `Context API` doesn't provide, also as **@danAbramov** mentioned

> React Redux uses context internally but it doesn’t expose this fact in
> the public API. So you should feel much safer using context via React
> Redux than directly because if it changes, the burden of updating the
> code will be on React Redux and not you.

Its up to Redux to actually update its implementation to adhere with the latest Context API.

The latest Context API can be used for Applications where you would simply be using Redux to pass data between components, however applications which use centralised data and handle API request in Action creators using `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` still would need Redux. Apart from this Redux has other libraries associated with it like `redux-persist` which allows you to save/store data in localStorage and rehydrate on refresh which is what the Context API still doesn't support.

As @dan_abramov mentioned in his blog [You might not need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367), Redux has useful applications like

> - Persist state to a local storage and then boot up from it, out of the box.
> - Pre-fill state on the server, send it to the client in HTML, and boot up from it, out of the box.
> - Serialize user actions and attach them, together with a state    snapshot, to automated bug reports, so that the product developers
>   can replay them to reproduce the errors.
> - Pass action objects over the network to implement collaborative    environments without dramatic changes to how the code is written.
> - Maintain an undo history or implement optimistic mutations without dramatic changes to how the code is written.
> - Travel between the state history in development, and re-evaluate > the current state from the action history when the code changes, ala TDD.
> - Provide full inspection and control capabilities to the development tooling so that product developers can build custom tools for their apps.
> - Provide alternative UIs while reusing most of the business logic.

With these many applications its far too soon to say that Redux will be replaced by the new Context API.

Comment: Ok, but what about reusability? The contexts are completely reusable, once redux + thunk, and especially redux + saga are barely.

Comment: @Daggett One thing we need to understand is redux is not context, it built on top of context, the store that you have is passed down by context, also can you elaborate what you mean by reusability

Comment: Even development of such a basic thing like reusable container with side effects becomes a nightmare with redux. Redux is tight to application level, and you may say, it's still reusable etc. etc., but saying reusable I mean totally reusable... With no spaghetti of spikes, built as a separate package, and could be reused independently to application setup.

Comment: @YuriiHaiovyi I agree with your questions. This answer is basically a compiled version of what the linked blog posts says. Nothing about sharing own perspective, like _I had been using only context, and then I got stuck, and felt it is a bad choice for some x, y, z reasons and then moved to Redux, Mobx that solved it.. or the reverse story_ for example. Mainly people is asking or searching this to see if there is some stories bad or good which may then help readers to think and make a calculated decisions... So my question what path you choose?

Comment: Which part of redux is not reusable? You could easily reuse reducers, selectors, actions and action creators in an another application with redux (react, even angular).

Answer (score 155):

**If you are using Redux only to avoid passing props down to deeply nested components**, then you could replace Redux with the `Context` API. It is exactly intended for this use case.

On the other hand, **if you are using Redux for everything else** (having a predictable state container, handling your application's logic outside of your components, centralizing your application's state, using [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) to track when, where, why, and how your application's state changed, or using plugins such as [Redux Form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/), [Redux Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), [Redux Undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo), [Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist), [Redux Logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger), etc…), then there is absolutely no reason for you to abandon Redux. The `Context` API doesn't provide any of this.

And I personally believe that **the Redux DevTools extension** is an amazing, underestimated debugging tool, which justifies by itself to keep using Redux.

Some references:

- [Redux Is Not Dead Yet!](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet)
- [You Might Not Need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367)
- [Do React Hooks Replace Redux?](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-redux-210bab340672)

Answer (score 32):

I prefer using redux with redux-thunk for making API calls (also using Axios) and dispatching the response to reducers. It is clean and easy to understand.

Context API is very specific to the react-redux part on how React components are connected to the store. For this, react-redux is good. But if you want to, since Context is officially supported, you could use the Context API instead of react-redux.

So, the question should be Context API vs react-redux, and not Context API vs redux. Also, the question is slightly opinionated. Since, I am familiar with react-redux and use it in all projects, I will continue to use it. (There is no incentive for me to change).

But if you are learning redux just today, and you have not used it anywhere, it is worth giving Context API a shot and replace react-redux with your custom Context API code. Maybe, it is much cleaner that way.

Personally, it is a question of familiarity. There is no clear reason to choose one over the other because they are equivalent. And internally, react-redux uses Context anyways.

Answer (score 20):

The only reasons to use Redux for me are:

- You want a global state object (for various reasons, like debuggability, persistence...)
- Your app is or will be big, and should scale to many developers: in such case you probably need a level of indirection (ie an event system): you fire events (in the past) and then people you don't know in your organisation can actually listen to them

You probably don't need the level of indirection for your whole app, so it's fine to mix styles and use local state/context and Redux both at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

> - **If you need to use middleware for various purposes.** For example logging actions, error reporting, dispatching other requests depending
>     on the server’s response, etc.
> - **When data coming from multiple endpoints influence single component/view.**
> - **When you want to have greater control over actions in your applications.** Redux enables tracking actions and data change, it
>     greatly simplifies debugging.
> - **If you don’t want server response to directly change the state of your application.** Redux adds a layer, where you can decide how, when
>     and if this data should be applied. The observer pattern. Instead of
>     creating multiple publishers and subscribers across the whole app, you
>     just connect components to Redux store.

From: [When to use Redux?](https://ideamotive.co/blog/redux-vs-context-api/)

Comment: this answers it for me: "When data coming from multiple endpoints influence single component/view."