# Is it right way to pass Redux store via React Context in Root Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, react-context

I'm scaffolding a large scale `React` application. In fact it is a advanced level of admin panel, I wanna use `Redux` for handling the global `state` of application and `Redux Saga` for asynchronous actions.

Few days ago I saw an article in [`medium`](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b), Which it's about new `React Context` API, It's awesome and useful.

Also I saw a useful `Stack Overflow` question about using `React Context`, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073) is about `React Context` vs `React` and my situation is some different.

In my case I wanna use `Redux` for controlling global `state` of application like `login`, global data and etc, and passing these data to all of components tree with `React Context`, is it a right way? is there a better way to leverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-redux` internally uses `context` to pass on the data to the component. With redux you can make use of `connect` and supply the data to the component that needs it. Its not necessary to use context for this purpose

For instance you have a Admin component, you can pass state values to it like

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Admin extends React.Component {
    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Admin);
```

You can learn more about it **[here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)**