# How to send Props from One state component to another state component in react js without Redux

Tags: reactjs

1. How can we send the props from one state component to another state component without using Redux also?
2. I want to send a props from child to parent, not parent to child - how can I achieve this in React.js?

Comment: React has the concept of downward data flow meaning sending data from Parent to Child... The state should be lifted up... You're headed in the wrong direction...

Comment: Apart from redux, you may also make use of React context to share common values between components. Also props are provided from parents to children and hence parent will already have those props

Comment: Please check this question too on context vs redux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073/react-context-vs-react-redux-when-should-i-use-each-one/49569183#49569183