# Any new solution to replace redux in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new with react js.
I made two components to send/receive data using props between them.

But it gets more complex, I feel like I need to replace them with other solution like redux. I wonder there is the latest better solution to replace redux now for communication between two react components.

Answer (score 3):

There was a lot of opinions between redux and context api like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073/react-context-vs-react-redux-when-should-i-use-each-one). But today, I can say yes, you can replace redux with just react itself. Because, currently react provides so much concepts just like the redux, [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can find [react additional hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) like useReducer, useCallback, useMemo, etc.

But arguably, redux is still worth for maintaining project easily. You can have redux devtool, keep the code clean (state in store - a separate place for concerns).

There are more concerns over this. You may see [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1063) what future react will have. You may also find the [medium blog](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/the-future-of-react-reducers-and-global-state-management-30cda8a3b082) helpful and the [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9tto1x/are_react_hooks_going_to_kill_redux/).

---

Worth Reading:

[State management with react hooks and context api](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c)

Answer (score 1):

Redux main task is to be a 'predictable state container', and, as you wrote, it also makes sharing data between components much easier. The main drawback is that it requires additional code, but I think that it is worth it.

For apps / websites that are not very small, I wouldn't use react / react native without it.

The way redux works may be a bit difficult to understand in the beginning. The following is a great article that helped me when I started using it: [redux connect explained](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/)