# React Native Context vs Redux vs AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am implementing an app where I can navigate to other users profiles. Obviously, entering to a profile have a cost for the database request, and also slows the user experience (having to wait for the db response to show the data).

Here comes AsyncStorage, a local database to cache objects and data from the DB. This API is deprecated, and some people is using redux with redux-persist instead...

In my app I am not using Redux, so to manage my purpose, I suppose I have to use AsyncStorage. But, what about React Context? Currently I have implemented a context provider "CurrentUserContext" which have a "VisitedUsers" map, in which I put the users data when I enter their profile (so to avoid unnecessary queries to the database, I only have to see if the data of that user is in this map). So, if a user want to see the most freshed data, he will have to refresh (the profile screen has a pull-to-refresh mechanism). Also, this context's life ends when the app is exited.

My question is: Is this a good option to use context for this kind of purposes? I have never seen anybody doing this... That is why I am doubtful.

From my point of view it's fine, since you really only have a short map (which gets done in a very short time) in a context that will last until the user closes the app or logs out.

Be careful, I ask it as a question, since I really don't know if this is a good practice. It should not be understood as "personal opinion".

Thank you.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073/react-context-vs-react-redux-when-should-i-use-each-one

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan after reading it, I have the same question. The answers explain when to use redux before context API, saying that some of the redux features are not provided in the new Context API. But, in my use  case, what I am doing is creating a kind of “HashMap of visited users” using the useRef hook in the Context Provider (to avoid unnecessary re-renders). So, if accessing data in a Map is fast, could this practice be wrong?

Comment: The only cons I see is that data doesn’t persist in the local storage... but there is a pro, I avoid consuming device memory. For me, this seems like some kind of persistance layer, like a Catalog for examine, where all data is in memory.

Comment: for example****

Comment: Yes it depends on your requirement, but reading from storage every time will have an impact

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using the `CurrentUserContext` to cache user profile data is actually quite intuitive, especially for reducing unnecessary database requests.

Here are some pros and cons of each method:

### 1. React Context

- **Pros**:

  - Easily integrates with React components and allows for global state management without prop drilling.
  - Suits well for session-specific data. If the data doesn't need to persist across app launches, the context is a good choice.
- **Cons**:

  - Data in context will be lost if the app is closed or crashes.
  - Might not be efficient for very large sets of data or frequent re-renders.

### 2. AsyncStorage

- **Pros**:

  - Data persists across app launches until explicitly deleted or the app is uninstalled.
  - Asynchronous operations, so reading and writing won't block the main thread.
- **Cons**

  - Limited to key-value storage. Complex data structures might need serialization.
  - Overhead of reading from storage every time data is needed if not kept in memory.

### 3. Redux, with redux-persist

- **Pros**:

  - Provides structured state management with a rich ecosystem.
  - `redux-persist` seamlessly integrates with Redux and persists part or all of your store.
- **Cons**:

  - Adds complexity and boilerplate code. If you're not already using Redux, this might be overkill for your needs.

Given your current setup, your use of the `VisitedUsers` map in the `CurrentUserContext` seems to be a suitable choice for caching user profile data during a session. It's simple and gets the job done. However, if you find a need to persist this cache across app launches, then you might want to explore integrating with AsyncStorage or a similar local storage solution.