# Using Redux or not for filter options

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux

I'm very new to React Native (did some courses) and now building my first app on my own which is going great, but I need some advice regarding user applied filters and how to handle this.

Quick summary of what needs to be done.

The user should be able to set some filters so only certain data is displayed and this state is saved even after closing the application, user logs in again and still sees only the data that is filtered because of the filter option he/she set before.

In one of my courses I got an introduction into Redux and my question here is should I use Redux for this feature or maybe Context for this ? My data is fetched from Firestore and I'm able to use  a query to filter data from firestore but that just ends up in many read/writes which cost money.

All advice is more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use redux
when you need some static state globally in your app then use context like open close drawer etc. For dynamic states go for redux

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49569183/15774176) :

> As Context is no longer an experimental feature and you can use
> Context in your application directly and it is going to be great for
> passing down data to deeply nested components which is what it was
> designed for.
>
> As Mark Erikson has written in his [blog](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/):
>
> If you're only using Redux to avoid passing down props, context could
> replace Redux - but then you probably didn't need Redux in the first
> place.
>
> Context also doesn't give you anything like the Redux DevTools, the
> ability to trace your state updates, middleware to add centralized
> application logic, and other powerful capabilities that Redux enables.
>
> Redux is much more powerful and provides a large number of features
> that the Context API doesn't provide, also as @danAbramov mentioned
>
> React Redux uses context internally but it doesn’t expose this fact in
> the public API. So you should feel much safer using context via React
> Redux than directly because if it changes, the burden of updating the
> code will be on React Redux and not you.
>
> It's up to Redux to actually update its implementation to adhere with
> the latest Context API.
>
> The latest Context API can be used for Applications where you would
> simply be using Redux to pass data between components, however
> applications which use centralized data and handle API requests in
> Action creators using redux-thunk or redux-saga still would need
> Redux. Apart from this Redux has other libraries associated with it
> like redux-persist which allows you to save/store data in localStorage
> and rehydrate on refresh which is what the Context API still doesn't
> support.

You can refer to the [blog1](https://www.ideamotive.co/blog/redux-vs-context-api) and [blog2](https://medium.com/@faizmohammed178/choosing-between-redux-and-reacts-context-api-272ca20224b2) in order to get more clarity on when to use redux and context.